# Laravel NOT return null - query builder

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
$u_t = User::where('set', '1')->get();
```

When I die and dump  `dd($u_t)` I get the following:

```
  Collection {#159 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => set {#158 ▶}
  ]
}
```

This is good so far. Now when I replace the "1" with some gibberish, like so:
    $u_t = User::where('set', 'adsfljasdlkf')->get();

I get:

```
 Collection {#164 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

I don't really get `null`. How can I return null?

Edit: when I do `->first()` instead of `->get()`, I get `null` if I enter junk. I don't get `null` if I replace it with `->get()`.

Answer (score 2):

When using `get()`, you're getting a collection of users, so it makes no sense for it to return `null`. It always returns a collection, regardless of how many users it found.

If you insist, you can change it to `null` yourself:

```php
$users = User::where('set', '1')->get();

if ($users->isEmpty()) {
    $users = null;
}
```